# How to config "tileLoadFunction" Openlayers v6.14.1 by axios in reactjs for adding WMS layers?

Tags: openlayers, wms, react

I'm trying to add GeoServer WMS layers to Openlayers map in reactjs, this is my code:

```
  setWMSLayers(wmsLayers=>[...wmsLayers,
      
      new TileLayer({
      source:new TileWMS({
        url:'http://194.5.195.11:8080/geoserver/wms?',
        visible:true,
        projection:'EPSG:4326',
        params:{'LAYERS':`${layerName}`,'TILED':true},
        serverType:'geoserver',
        tileLoadFunction:async(imageTile, src)=>{

       await axios({
          method:"GET",
          url:src,
          responseType:'blob',
        
          headers:{
            'Content-Type':'text/html'
          },
          auth:{
            username:'admin',
            password:'gTv6_*****'
          }
          }).then((response)=>{

            
           imageTile.getImage().src = response;
          })
        
          
        }
    
      })
    
    })])
```

I'm going to know correct configuration for "tileLoadFunction" with axios library or fetch api?
I can't use xhr XMLHttpRequest method exist in Openlayers document, because react use virtuallDOM.

I'm using Openlayers v6.14.1, reactjs v16, axios 0.24.0, GeoServer 2.20.2

Comment: IF `URL` is supported you can use `imageTile.getImage().src = URL.createObjectURL(response)`

Comment: I did test, it didn't work :(